# Loading Screen Libgdx Assetmanager

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Trying to create a loading screen, I have a `Assets` class and a `LoadingScreen` class which is called immediately from:

```
this.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this));
```

At loading screen I have this:

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
    final Game1 game;
    Sprite LdScreen;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    public LoadingScreen(Game1 gam){
        game=gam;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);

    }

    public void show() {
        Texture LdscreenTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Background.png"));
        LdScreen =  new Sprite (LdscreenTexture);
        Assets.manager.finishLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(LdScreen, 0,0);
        game.batch.end();
        Assets.manager.update();
        if(Assets.manager.update() == true){
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
        }
}
```

But it always returns and error, as though it tries to move to `MainMenuScreen` class and the asset isn't loaded, which it should be if `Assets.manager.update()` is true right?
Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 2):

this simple example

.//Add in your Class Game1

Variable Class

```
private AssetManager yourAssetManager;
```

Created Method

```
yourAssetManager = new AssetManager();
```

Get Set Method

```
public AssetManger getManger(){
 return this.yourAssetManager;
}
```

.

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
final Game1 game;
Sprite LdScreen;
OrthographicCamera camera;
AssetManager yourAssetManager;

public LoadingScreen(Game1 gam){
    game=gam;
    this.yourAssetManager = game.getManager();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);

}

public void show() {
```

Use yourAssetManager.load(.... for load asset

```
     yourAssetManager.load("data/Background.png", Texture.class);

    Texture LdscreenTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Background.png"));
    LdScreen =  new Sprite (LdscreenTexture);
    //Assets.manager.finishLoading();
}

@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(LdScreen, 0,0);
        game.batch.end();
        //Assets.manager.update();
        if(yourAssetManger.update()){
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
        }
}
```

read this link https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets i,m not right now test sorry.