# error with loading screen assetmanager libgdx java

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I currently have 2 classes, an Assets class and a loading screen class:
Assets class:

```
public class Assets {

    public static AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static void queueLoading() {
        (..)
        manager.load("sound/startScreen.mp3", Music.class);
        (..)

        while(!manager.update())
        {
            System.out.println("Loaded: " + manager.getProgress() *100 + "%");
        }       
    }
    public static boolean isLoaded() {
        if(manager.getProgress() >= 1)
            return true;
        return false;
        //return manager.update();
    }
}
```

Loading screen::

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
    final Game1 game;
    Sprite LdScreen;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    public LoadingScreen(Game1 gam){
        game=gam;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);

    }

    public void show() {
        Texture LdscreenTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Background.png"));
        LdScreen =  new Sprite (LdscreenTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(LdScreen, 0,0);
        game.batch.end();
        Assets.manager.update();
        if(Assets.manager.update() == true){
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
            System.out.print("test");
        }
}
```

The problem is this doesn't work, when I run it immediately `Assets.manager.update` returns true and I get an error saying that the assets are not found for `MainMenuScreen`, clear as they have not been loaded. And when i comment out `game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));` I get the 'test' written to the console but I don't get the progress to the console from my Assets class. This leads me to think that when I run I the `Asset.smanager.update` always returns true, and it isn't loading the assets at all.

I have looked at tutorials and the wiki, but I have not found them to be useful. Any ideas?

Comment: posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462904/loading-screen-libgdx-assetmanager

Comment: Is it because `Assets.queueLoading` was never invoked so your Asset manager has nothing in it?