# Asynchronously Loading Screen Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I store all of my assets in a class and load them at the start of my game, I am trying to create a loading screen in a separate class.

Asset manager class:

```
public class Assets {


    public static AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static void queueLoading() {
        (..)
        manager.load("sound/buttonpress.mp3", Sound.class);
        (..)
        while(!manager.update())
        {
            System.out.println("Loaded: " + manager.getProgress() *100 + "%");
        }

    }
    public static boolean update() {
        return manager.update();
    }
}
```

Loading screen class:

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
    final Game1 game;
    Sprite LdScreen;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    public LoadingScreen(Game1 gam){
        game=gam;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);

    }

    public void show() {
        Texture LdscreenTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Background.png"));
        LdScreen =  new Sprite (LdscreenTexture);
        Assets.queueLoading();
        }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(LdScreen, 0,0);
        game.batch.end();
//      Assets.queueLoading();
        if(Assets.update()){
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
            System.out.print("hllasgsgsag");
        }
    Assets.update();
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

**Problem:**

When i run it in the console i get the progress percentage, but the screen stays black whilst it is loading (stuck at Assets class), then it flashes to the loading screen, and changes to `MainMenuScreen`.
How do I stop the black screen when the assets are loading?

Comment: posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468382/error-with-loading-screen-assetmanager-libgdx-java

Comment: @AngelAngel That answer did not solve this slightly different issue, also I have more specified the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is because you are loading all the Assets straight away and this isn't done in a different thread and is run whilst the screen is being shown. I would advise using `manager.update(delta)` which should be called during your game loop and getting the update percentage. The full source would be a bit difficult for me to explain but I have done something similar in my previous projects, the sources are available on GitHub below:

The Assets class:
https://github.com/basimkhajwal/NinjaTower/blob/master/NinjaTower/core/src/net/net63/codearcade/NinjaTower/utils/Assets.java

The Loading Screen:
https://github.com/basimkhajwal/NinjaTower/blob/master/NinjaTower/core/src/net/net63/codearcade/NinjaTower/screens/MainMenuScreen.java